# Every sequence of sets have coverging subsequence

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Is that true, that every sequence of sets have coverging subsequence? We say that sequence of sets $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ coverging iff ${\limsup}_{n \to \infty} A_n = {\liminf}_{n \to \infty} A_n$

Comment: can one explain the differences from the sequence of say real numbers?

Comment: You dont know definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of set sequence or you ask why we cant translate proof from real numbers to sets?

Comment: I know the definitions, the second one. Like just taking a sine function for which we have liminf=-1 but limsup=1. Every value of a sine function can be a singleton set.

Comment: Because proof of real numbers based on linear order and completness theorem and we dont have something like that for sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider $$A_n = \left\{ f \in \{ 0, 1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} : f(n) = 1 \right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Beautiful example!

Comment: You're welcome. :-)